# causal impact R package- finding individual day values

Tags: r, time-series

In the causal impact R package is there a way to get the counterfactual values and confidence intervals for each day rather than average or cumulative?

Answer (score 1):

Pointwise inferences are stored in `$series`. For example:

```
> impact <- CausalImpact(data, pre.period, post.period)

> names(impact$series)

 [1] "response"           "cum.response"       "point.pred"        
 [4] "point.pred.lower"   "point.pred.upper"   "cum.pred"          
 [7] "cum.pred.lower"     "cum.pred.upper"     "point.effect"      
[10] "point.effect.lower" "point.effect.upper" "cum.effect"        
[13] "cum.effect.lower"   "cum.effect.upper"
```

The column `response` is a copy of the first column in your `data`, and `cum.response` is a cumulative version of it. The remaining columns contain posterior expectations and lower and upper interval limits of the pointwise and cumulative counterfactuals, and of the pointwise and cumulative causal effects.